# Load Testing an API with Firebase Custom Token

Tags: firebase, performance, testing, load, fastapi

I have my FastAPI secured with Firebase Auth.

My app sings in using Firebase Phone Auth, requests a Custom Firebase Token from my FastAPI server to gain extra custom claims, and signs in using the Custom Token in de App automatically. This last token is then used to authenticate further with my API.

Now my problem is; how can I load test my API with this, for example with 1k/10k/20k concurrent users?

Kind regards.

Comment: Did you try [Locust](https://locust.io/)?

Comment: @Irfanuddin yes i am looking into locust. But how can I generate fake users so I can Authenticate with my API using a Firebase Token?

Comment: @Theo did you find out?